# How to Detect Editor if it is in EXM body editor

Tags: experience-editor, exm

Is there a way to detect the experience editor I am at is the editor in Email Experience Manager message body?

Comment: Which version of EXM is this?

Answer (score 1):

In Sitecore 8.2, if you edit a message from the Experience Editor, there are 2 parameters added to the url which allows you later to determine if you're in EXM message editor:

- `sc_mode=edit` - just info that you're in editing mode
- `exm=1` - info that you're in EXM editing mode